# Google calendar api for organization

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'm working on one school app. I'm able to create events using google calender API with NodeJS. I created the clientID and secretID on the school google account. Every time event is created, only the admin has access to start the meeting. But I want teachers(who are creating the event) to be the organizer. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `organizer` field of an event is a **read-only** field. You can use the [`move`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move) action to move the event and change the organizer but this can only be done if the authenticated user has write access to the destination calendar.

A solution would be to use a service account and perform domain wide delegation. In this way you will be able to **impersonate** the user in question and organize the event wanted.

According to the *Service accounts* [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts):

> A service account is a special kind of account used by an application or a virtual machine (VM) instance, not a person. Applications use service accounts to make authorized API calls.

As for performing domain-wide delegation, you might want to take a look into this:

> In enterprise applications you may want to programmatically access users data without any manual authorization on their part. In G Suite domains, the domain administrator can grant to third party applications domain-wide access to its users' data — this is referred as domain-wide delegation of authority. To delegate authority this way, domain administrators can use service accounts with OAuth 2.0.

#### Reference

- [Calendar API - Events:move](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/move);
- [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts);
- [Calendar API - Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-g-suite-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority);
- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account).